# How to build 32 bit c-shared library from go-lang code?

Tags: c, go

I have a code go-lang which itself is a standalone application. But part of it I want to externalize as c-shared library for the consumers which are running on 32bit(386) architecture. I tried executing the below command, but it is failing.

`go build -o 386 insuanceCalculator.so -buildmode=c-shared ./src/packageName/insuanceCalculator.go`

And I am getting following error

`can't load package: package main: build constraints exclude all Go files in /Users/user1/Documents/go/insuranceCalcProject/src/packageName
make: *** [installLib] Error 1`

Comment: Please check the command you're using to build. You're trying to build an object named `386`, the arguments and flags are out of order, and you should be building a package, not an individual file.

Comment: I agree I made a mistake, but then I passed cross compilation params like below.

```CGO_ENABLED=1 GOARCH=386 go build -o 386 insuanceCalculator.so -buildmode=c-shared ./src/packageName/insuanceCalculator.go```

but now I am getting below error.

```In file included from /usr/include/features.h:371,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25,
                 from _cgo_export.c:2:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory```

I believe it is looking for 32 bit C libraries?

Comment: If you're compiling for 32bit with cgo, then it's going to look for 32bit C libraries. Make sure you can compile a 32bit C program on its own. (and your command still doesn't make sense, what is `insuanceCalculator.so` supposed to be doing in the arguments? See `go help build` for the appropriate options)

Comment: And also, my project has more than one file with main() function, so I had to specify which file with main function I need to build the library from.

Comment: The go tools primarily are used on packages, so if you have multiple `main` functions, you need to separate those into proper packages. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)